# Passing variable in PHP POST loses data type and becomes a string

Tags: javascript, html, post

I am having trouble posting a stripe token to a page. Here with the form below, I create the token and post it to the page 'bankverify.php' but for some reason when I var_dump() the token on the page it is posted to, this is the response
 : 'string(15) "[object Object]" ' Somehow it is being converted to a string instead of keeping its token properties and information. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
<form id="stripe-form" action="bankverify2.php?name=<?php echo $_POST["firstName"] .' '. $_POST["lastName"] ?>" method="post">
              <input id="stripe-token" type="hidden" name="token" />
            </form>
            <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
            <script>
            var stripe = Stripe('public key');
            stripe.createToken('bank_account', {
            country: 'US',
            currency: 'usd',
            routing_number: '<?php echo $_POST["routingNumber"];?>',
            account_number: '<?php echo $_POST["accountNumber"];?>',
            account_holder_name: '<?php echo $_POST["firstName"] .' '.$_POST["lastName"];?>',
            account_holder_type: 'individual',
          }).then(function(result) {

            // Handle result.error or result.token
            if (result.token) 
            {
                console.log(result.token);
                var tokenBank = result.token;
                $('#stripe-token').val(tokenBank);
                $('#stripe-form').submit();
            }
```

This is the code for the page that receives it:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("secret key");
$token = $_POST['token'];
var_dump($token);
```

Comment: Everything sent from a form or sent on the querystring is converted to a string

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(tokenBank)` ?

Comment: Maybe you should use `result.id` or `result.token.id` instead of `result.token` https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/v2#card-createToken

Comment: Usually it's a really bad idea to post your private api key in a public forum. The exception is when it's an api key for a payment gateway. Then it's a really really bad idea.